# Keeping data from db syned with horizontal scale

Tags: java, architecture, relational-database, microservices, horizontal-scaling

Lets assume we have a microservice "A". We are now scaling it horizontally, meaning we have 3 instances of "A" working on the same db instance (and schemea, in general assume the 3 "A" instances might do Read and Writes on the same data).

Now I'll demonstrate the question with some pseudo code, we have the following update function in "A":

```
Product p = getProdFromDb(); // for example selecting 
// from Postgresql db

p.updateInnerData(); // synch method that updates 
// something inside the p model that takes significant 
// amount of time
p.updateInDb(); //  for example update back in postgresql
```

The problem here is that other "A" instances might change product p while we are updating it here (not in this function, but asdume there such other functions that change products in "A").
One solution that I know of is using a lock on the db (for example using "Select ... for Update") but it creates a performance bottleneck in this function.
I would like to see better solutions that solves this problem without this bottleneck, real examples in Java (or JS) would be very helpful.

Edit: assume partioning is not an option

Comment: please explain what is the performance bottleneck you want to improve. you want select to be faster, or update?

Comment: I wan't all of them to work fast without using locks (if its possible)

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of locking: pessimistic (the one that you try to avoid) and optimistic locking.

In optimistic locking you do not hold any lock but try to save the document; if the document was already modified at the same time (meaning it was modified since we loaded it) then you retry the entire process (load + mutate + save).

One way of doing it is to have a `version` column that is increased every time you mutate the entity. When you try to persist, you expect that the entity with `version = version + 1` does not exists. If it already exists, then it means that a concurrent update has happened and you retry (load + mutate + save).

In pseudocode, the algorithm is like this:

```
function updateEntity(ID, load, mutate, create)

    do
    {
        entity, version = load(ID) or create entity
        entity = mutate entity
        updateRow(that matches the ID and version) and increment version
    }
    while (row has not changed and was not inserted)
```

I will give you also a code sample in PHP (hope it's easy to understand) for MongoDB:

```
class OptimisticMongoDocumentUpdater
{

    public function addOrUpdate(Collection $collection, $id, callable $hidrator, callable $factory = null, callable $updater, callable $serializer)
    {
        /**
         * We try to add/update the entity in a concurrent safe manner
         * using optimistic locking: we always try to update the existing version;
         * if another concurrent write has finished before us in the mean time
         * then retry the *whole* updating process
         */

        do {
            $document = $collection->findOne([
                '_id' => new ObjectID($id),
            ]);

            if ($document) {
                $version = $document['version'];
                $entity = \call_user_func($hidrator, $document);
            } else {
                if (!$factory) {
                    return;//do not create if factory does not exist
                }
                $entity = $factory();
                $version = 0;
            }

            $entity = $updater($entity);

            $serialized = $serializer($entity);

            unset($serialized['version']);

            try {
                $result = $collection->updateOne(
                    [
                        '_id'     => new ObjectID($id),
                        'version' => $version,
                    ],
                    [
                        '$set' => $serialized,
                        '$inc' => ['version' => 1],
                    ],
                    [
                        'upsert' => true,
                    ]
                );
            } catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\WriteException $writeException) {
                $result = $writeException->getWriteResult();
            }

        } while (0 == $result->getMatchedCount() && 0 == $result->getUpsertedCount());//no side effect? then concurrent update -> retry
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense, but I don't understand where the check of versions come to place in the code sample.
I'm also not sure if this removes the bottleneck, its a change for sure, but if for instance, you need to handle 10,000 update requests like this in parallel in mutiple instance of your service, you gonn'a still wait for a lot of time

Comment: @ZivGlazer this code tries to update the entity that match some  `_id` and `version`, (the `version` that was when the object was loaded); if it cannot find an entity with that version it means it was already updated in parallel.

Comment: @ZivGlazer it is faster if the requests are not on the same entity because there is no lock held.

Comment: From what I understand you kind of implemented the lock in the server code insteaad of using a traditional db lock. Also db lock can work on specific rows (in relational dbs I think, not sure about nosql) so its the better to use db locks

Comment: @ZivGlazer no locks, really. See it for yourself. Just a simple update with a query based on version

Comment: It's nkt a traditional db lock, but a lock concept implemented in your code. Look at this example of what I mean (Its not exactly the same as your mechanism but I think you will get my point) http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-explicit-lock-example

Comment: @ZivGlazer no, it's not, not even conceptually. Please see that in my algorithm, an update command go directly to the database, without waiting for anything, there is no synchronization whatsoever. The idea is to update the entity only if has not been updated in the mean time. Are you having trouble understanding PHP?

Comment: @ZivGlazer I added a pseudocode, see my updated answer

Comment: I think its conceptually same (or close to) a lock because you got a thread stuck in a loop until the resource is free, the difference in your code is that its stuck until the versions line up (=the resource is free = not locked sort of speak). I'm not saying its not a good solution, also from my knowledge of Mongo you have to implement a lot of stuffs in your own code, but its not a substantial change from using a lock in a traditional db

Comment: @ZivGlazer I see what you are saying but there is a big difference in **performance**:  they lineup by default -> if you don't have concurrent modifications of *the same entity* there is no performance penalty (as in ZERO, nada, nul, nichts).

Comment: And if you use a db lock, and you don't have concurrent modifications, will there be a performance issue?

Comment: @ZivGlazer as you already said: "One solution that I know of is using a lock on the db"

Answer (score 2):

In my answer, I assume you want 100% reliability.

If that's the case, you can divide your tables to many pages, where each page will contains X amount of rows. when you try to update a table, you will only lock that page, but then there will be more I/O.

Also, on your db, you can configure it so that a select command will read even uncommited rows, which will improve speed - for SQL server, it's `SELECT WITH (NOLOCK)`

Answer (score 0):

If `p.updateInnerData();` takes time X and you have a high IO rate that might send Y no new requests to the microservice, then the function itself is posing performance bottleneck. Ideally microservice db related operations should be designed crisp performance benchmarks in mind; this often leads us to choice of the database itself which enables the high/expected IOPS you want to achieve.

1. With RDBMS being target database, one possible option might be to decouple the expensive db operation pertaining `p.updateInnerData();` and make it async over a reliable messaging platform that ensures strict ordering w/o compromising speed; e.g. Kafka; we can even think of backing up the messaging through storing the `p` object/changes in itself like a BLOB/JSON in a Db table and immediately return the control to user and then triggering the message asynchronously.
2. With NoSQL being target database, we would want to choose based on our READ/WRITE needs and thus largely reducing write and read related latency.